# change text of <a> element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array with contains a bunch of anchor elements like this:

```js
["<a href="#" id="id1">First anchor<a>", "<a href="#" id="id2">Second anchor<a>", "<a href="#" id="id3">Third anchor<a>"]
```

I would like to change just the text in the last anchor element (Third anchor) while keeping the attributes of the anchor element itself unchanged (meaning I want to keep my id and href attributes intact). How would I do this and returned the changed array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an array of anchor tags is what you wanted, then jQuery's `map` method would make this trivial:

```
var strings = ["<a href='#' id='id1'>First anchor</a>", "<a href='#' id='id2'>Second anchor</a>", "<a href='#' id='id3'>Third anchor</a>"];

var anchor_elements = $.map(strings, function(el){
  return $(el).get();
});
```

You can now easily change the text of any element with jQuery:

```
$(anchor_elements[2]).text('New text');
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have an array of anchor elements, you have an array of strings. And you have a big syntax error since you've tried to include double-quotes inside double-quoted strings without escaping them. Anyway:

```
var array = ["<a href=\"#\" id=\"id1\">First anchor<a>", "<a href=\"#\" id=\"id2\">Second anchor<a>", "<a href=\"#\" id=\"id3\">Third anchor<a>"];

array[2] = array[2].replace(/^(<[^>]+>)([^<]*)(<)/,
                            "$1" + "yourreplacementtexthere" + "$3");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/byQcW/

Answer (score 3):

There are few syntax problems in the array related to using `'` and `"` also the closing tag for `a` is wrong

```
array = ['<a href="#" id="id1">First anchor</a>', '<a href="#" id="id2">Second anchor</a>', '<a href="#" id="id3">Third anchor</a>'];
array[2] = array[2].replace(/(<a[^>]*?>)(.*)(<\/a>)/, '$1' + 'replacerstring' + '$3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var arr = ['<a href="#" id="id1">First anchor<a>', '<a href="#" id="id2">Second anchor<a>', '<a href="#" id="id3">Third anchor<a>']  
arr[2] = $(arr[2]).text('Your text here').prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: Won't that change the third element from a string to an actual DOM element?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, it seems like it. The output of `console.log` does change in Chrome Dev Tools.